# Install python 3.5 via conda get unsatisfiable error "backport.os"

Tags: python

I install anaconda with python version 3.7 on Windows.
Then I want to install TensorFlow, but it don't support python 3.7.
I try to install python 3.5, but get this error:
[image: python error]

How to resolve this conflict to install python 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an environment with the Python version of your choice.

Example create an environment called deep with python 3.5 and tensorflow:

```
conda create -n deep python=3.5 tensorflow
```

After that we can activate it with

```
conda activate deep
```

While in this environment you will have Python 3.5 and tensorflow. You can add other packages to your environment anywhere. E.g. adding latest scipy, pandas, and jupyter

```
conda install --name deep scipy pandas jupyter
```

Updated: While in the environment, you don’t have to specify the environment name, when installing packages. You can do:

```
conda install package_name
```

When done doing awesomeness, you can deactivate as so:

```
conda deactivate
```

;)
So your workflow when working with Tensorflow, would include activating your ‘deep’ environment and use Python 3.5 there ;) e.g.

```
conda activate deep
jupyter lab
```

Assuming you have installed tensorflow and jupyter, this will start a service on your default browser where you can start building your project.

Happy coding ...

Check out conda documentation https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html

Comment: If you are in an active environment (`source activate <name>`), it's not necessary to specify the environment name to install new packages to the activated environment (just use `conda install scipy pandas`).

Comment: That is true. When in the environment you do not have to start the name. conda activate envName/conda deactivate are cross platforms. Otherwise source activate envName/source deactivate works in Linux, while Windows source is not dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Today Tensorflow doesn't support Python 3.7 . You have to create a new environment with Python 3.4, 3.5 or 3.6. With `conda` it's easy to handle different environments and versions. In addition it's [recommended](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) using `pip` to install Tensorflow.

Python 3.6 with CPU:

```
conda create -y -n name_of_env python=3.6  # create new environment
source activate name_of_env                # activate the new environment
pip install tensorflow                     # install tensorflow
```

Python 3.6 with GPU ([please check the additional setup for using a GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu)):

```
conda create -y -n name_of_env python=3.6
source activate name_of_env
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Tip: Finally you can test your installation with the following command:

```
echo 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)' | python
# 1.12.0
```

Comment: I had that that is not true. Conda is recommend over pip in installing tensorflow https://towardsdatascience.com/stop-installing-tensorflow-using-pip-for-performance-sake-5854f9d9eb0c